# Jquery addClass and Remove Class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

Okay i would like to add a class `cfse_a` to an element `#searchput` when the mouse is hovering over the element and then when the mouse is not hovering over the element then remove class `cfse_a`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/, http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event with [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods:

```
$("#searchput").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("cfse_a");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("cfse_a");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/G23EA/

Comment: @AndersEriksson If it works like a charm, you should upvote the answer and not downvote it.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#searchput').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('cfse_a'); // add class when mouseover happen
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('cfse_a'); // remove class when mouseout happen
});
```

You can also use:

```
$('#searchput').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('cfse_a');
});
```

see [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/BAN7V/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
  $("#searchput").hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass("cfse_a");
     }, function() {
   $(this).removeClass("cfse_a");
   });
```

Use it.hope it help !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
$('#searchput').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('cfse_a');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('cfse_a');
});
```